# Install version specific MongoDB with Ansible

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ansible, yaml

I have tried to search this a lot but, I am not able to find any proper solution.

I want to install MongoDB 4.2 on 3 machines using Ansible but I don't know how to specify the version.

My OS is **Ubuntu Server 20.04**

Below yml file is causing version error

```yaml
---
# tasks file for mongoDB setup

- hosts: ec2
  become: true
  
  tasks:
    - name: Install aptitude using apt
      apt: 
        name: aptitude 
        state: latest 
        update_cache: yes  
    
    - name: install mongoDB
      apt: 
        name: mongodb=4.2
        state: present
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Ensure mongodb is running and and enabled to start automatically on reboots
      systemd:
        name: mongodb
        enabled: yes
        state: started
```

Here is the error

> TASK [install mongoDB]
> ********************************************************* fatal: [13.232.181.230]: FAILED! => {"cache_update_time": 1620583763,
> "cache_updated": true, "changed": false, "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-get -y
> -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef" -o "Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold"      install 'mongodb=4.2''
> failed: E: Version '4.2' for 'mongodb' was not found\n", "rc": 100,
> "stderr": "E: Version '4.2' for 'mongodb' was not found\n",
> "stderr_lines": ["E: Version '4.2' for 'mongodb' was not found"],
> "stdout": "Reading package lists...\nBuilding dependency
> tree...\nReading state information...\n", "stdout_lines": ["Reading
> package lists...", "Building dependency tree...", "Reading state
> information..."]}

What is the proper way to install version specific MongoDB on remote machines.

Comment: What is the error your get?

Comment: How would you specify the version if using apt on the command line directly ? Just write the name the exact same way This question has nothing to do with ansible, not either with programming at all and is therefore off-topic here. If you are still having difficulties, try https://superuser.com

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I have updated the post with error message.

Comment: Are you able to install (outdated) Mongo 4.2 manually with `apt`?

Comment: If I try to install this manually using the Linux terminal, I can do that successfully. This time I am trying to use Ansible so I could install this on multiple machines easily.

Comment: @Zeitounator, for manual installation here are the [**steps**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-18-04-source)

Comment: You are linking a tutorial in which the used name for the package is `mongodb-org` after installing a specific apt repository. Just compare with your above test and see the difference. And once more: this is for https://superuser.com. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would like to thank **Zeitounator** and **Wernfried Domscheit** for help. I appreciate that.

I was making multiple mistakes.

- They key was wrong
- The repository information was missing
- The name of the mongo installation package was wrong.
- The mongo service check was incorrect.

Below is the correct yml file, and it's working fine.
I am installing `Mongo 4.4`. The steps will remain the same for 4.2. You will have to make sure the key path and repo.

### Solution

```yaml
---
# tasks file for mongoDB setup

- hosts: ec2
  become: true
  
  tasks:
    - name: Install aptitude using apt
      apt: 
        name: aptitude 
        state: latest 
        update_cache: yes 
    
    - name: Import public key
      apt_key:
        url: 'https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc'
        state: present
    
    - name: Add repository
      apt_repository:
        filename: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list'
        repo: 'deb https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse'
        state: present
        update_cache: yes
    
    - name: Install mongoDB
      apt: 
        name: mongodb-org
        state: present
        update_cache: yes

    - name: Ensure mongodb is running and and enabled to start automatically on reboots
      service: 
        name: mongod 
        enabled: yes
        state: started
```